# How can I get the absolute path of an image selected from google drive instead of gallery for fixing it's orientation?

Tags: android, image, cloud, image-rotation

In my app, am trying to let the user select an image from the phone storage and display it. Trying to do so, I've faced a problem that the image is returned rotated. So after some search I found some code snippets that helped me to do it right. But testing the same strategy on images selected from google drive or any cloud storage gives an error.

---

Here are the code snippets I use to get the absolute path and modify the image rotation.

```
 private static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String filePath = "";
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    Log.d("here", wholeID);
    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("here", filePath);
    return filePath;
}

    public static Bitmap modifyOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, String image_absolute_path) throws IOException {
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(image_absolute_path);
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return rotate(bitmap, 90);

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return rotate(bitmap, 180);

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return rotate(bitmap, 270);

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            return flip(bitmap, true, false);

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            return flip(bitmap, false, true);

        default:
            return bitmap;
    }
}

    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, float degrees) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degrees);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preScale(horizontal ? -1 : 1, vertical ? -1 : 1);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

And finally am using the modify method here, after getting a bitmap:

```
public static String encodeImgToBase64(Uri uri, Context context) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
    inputStream.close();
    inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, REQUIRED_WIDTH, REQUIRED_HEIGHT);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
    inputStream.close();

    bitmap = modifyOrientation(bitmap, getRealPathFromURI(context, uri));

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imgByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imgByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

So, my question is how to do the same thing on images selected from a cloud storage ?

Comment: `public static Bitmap modifyOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, String image_absolute_path)`. A bitmap? How did you obtain a bitmap from what the user selected from google drive?

Comment: I'm using some other function, do you need it ?

Comment: `How did you obtain a bitmap from what the user selected from google drive?`. My god.. why do i have to ask that twice?

Comment: @greenapps checkout the post, I've edited it.

Comment: Thanks. In your whole story you did not tell us why you need a file path. We have to 'discover' that from the code. Please tell the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can try download the image, save in device tmp storage then you can use same method that you used for gallery image to it.

Comment: It's an acceptable work around actually, but I prefer a more direct way if there is one.
Thanks anyways